# Trying to get the @{Name= out of the output

Tags: powershell

I have a script that has an array of custom PSObjects with only 2 items each. I need to sort on the first value in each object and then spit out both items, but they are both coming out with `@{Name=` and `@{Line=`. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
$expinfo = @()
<<<>>>
$dbinfo = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$dbname = Get-Item $folder | select Name
$dbinfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName DBName -NotePropertyValue "$dbname"

$dbinfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ExportLine -NotePropertyValue "$eline"
$expinfo += $dbinfo
<<<>>>
foreach ($expdb in ($expinfo.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object DBName))
{
    $dbn = $expdb | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DBName
    $dbe = $expdb | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExportLine
    $dbn
    $dbe
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
@{Name=AIT1PD}
@{Line=20180312.1700 20180312.1704 All items successfully completed.}
@{Name=APAC1PD}
@{Line=20180313.0100 20180313.0120 All items successfully completed.}
```

I would like for it to look like this:

```
AIT1PD 20180312.1700 20180312.1704 All items successfully completed.
APAC1PD 20180313.0100 20180313.0120 All items successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Add-Member` statements to add the property value you're interested in:

```
$dbinfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName DBName -NotePropertyValue $dbname.Name
$dbinfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ExportLine -NotePropertyValue $eline.Line
```

Assuming you're using PowerShell 3.0 or newer, I'd suggest using the `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator instead:

```
$dbinfo = [pscustomobject]@{
    DBName     = (Get-Item $folder).Name
    ExportLine = $eline.Line
}
```

Comment: Darn you... just about to post when i saw there was an update.

Comment: [pew pew :)](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/DefensiveChubbyIchthyostega-size_restricted.gif)

Comment: How is there not a dupe for this... I am having issues finding a good one. Op is even using `-ExpandProperty` in his example...

Comment: Thanks a ton! I just wasn't getting it on my own. I appreciate the fast responses.